# Calling Azure DevOps REST API in a daemon app or long-running task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm writing Azure WebJob (long running task) to create a WorkItems pragmatically. I created Azure AD App (SPN) and added Visual Studio Team Services under API permissions. I created console application to test API and here is the code to get the token and calling DevOps API

```
static async Task RunAsync()
{
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority); // https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tanent}
    ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey); // Azure APP ID and Key
    AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientCredential); // 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(baseAddress + "/_apis/wit/workitemtypes?api-version=5.1-preview.2"); // https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

I am getting HTML output with title: "Azure DevOps Services | Sign In" instead of JSON response (list of work item types). Since it's background process I cannot ask user a prompt for login. Can I do this way? Is it supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using default authentication of Azure DevOps REST API, and it is using OAuth 2.0 authentication model.

For your own needs to eliminate callbacks and OAuth authentication from Azure DevOps Sign in, use Azure DevOps PAT (Personal Access Token) instead.

Create a PAT for the account that will call the APIs, and adjust your code that calls the REST API according to the this Microsoft's official documentation:
[Create Azure DevOps Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=vsts)

Comment: Is there a way to access without using PAT, can we achieve this using SPN ?

Comment: @leox you are asking different question. Please submit new question instead of asking in comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do this way? Is it supported?

Short answer is **no**.

During require permission to the Azure Devops service, we could find that there is no application permission supported, the only way is delegate permission. Signed-in user is required. For more information about type of Azure AD permission, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent#types-of-permissions).

> **Delegated** permissions - Are used by apps that have a **signed-in user** present. For these apps, either the user or an administrator consents to the permissions that the app requests and the app is delegated permission to act as the signed-in user when making calls to an API. Depending on the API, the user may not be able to consent to the API directly and would instead require an administrator to provide "admin consent".

[image]

As Eriawan Kusumawardhono mentioned that you could use the PAT way to call the Azure DevOps REST API. For more information, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=vsts).